# zend_db and join

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I am trying to understand how to use Zend_DB in my program but I have some problems. The class below (DatabaseService) works when I pass it  a simple query. However, if I pass it a query with a join clause my page just hangs and no error is returned. I cut and paste the qry in a query browser and it is valid

Any help would be great

```
$SQL = "select name from mytable"

$db = new DatabaseService($dbinfo)

$db ->fetchall($SQL )  // works

-----------------------------------------------------------
$SQL = "select count(*) as cnt from EndPoints join CallID on EndPoints.`CallID` = CallID.CallID where EndPoints.LastRegister >= '2010-04-21 00:00:01' and EndPoints.LastRegister <= '2010-04-21 23:59:59' "

$db = new DatabaseService($dbinfo)

$db ->fetchall($SQL )  // DOES NO WORK
```

---

```
class DatabaseService
{


 function DatabaseService($dbinfo,$dbname="")
 {

  try
  {
  $dbConfig = array( 
      'host'     => $this->host,
    'username' => $this->username,
    'password' => $password,
    'dbname'   => $this->dbname );

                 $this->db = Zend_Db::factory($this->adapter, $dbConfig); 

      Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($this->db);
  }
  catch(Zend_Exception $e)
  {
   $this->error = $e->getMessage();
   Helper::log($this->error);
   return false;
  }
 }

 public function connnect()
 {
  if($this->db !=null)
  {
   try

   {
    $this->db->getConnection(); 
       return true; 
   }
   catch (Zend_Exception $e) 
   {   
    $err = "FAILED ::".$e->getMessage()." <br />";


   }
  }
  return false;
 } 

 public function fetchall($sql)
 {

  $res= $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
  return $res;

 }
}
```

Comment: When you say you're able to paste it into a query browser, are you just checking syntax or are you actually able to get the result set back from the query? Also, what version of the Zend Framework are you using, and what database adapter are you working with (value of `$this->adapter`)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why that wouldn't work.  It could be a bug in a particular release of ZF but as far as I can tell there are no SQL syntax errors.  What you could do is Bootstrap the Zend_Db class somewhere in your system like in the index.php file just as you were doing in your DatabaseService class:

```
$dbConfig = array(
    'host'     => 'hostname',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname'   => 'dbname'
);

$db = Zend_Db::factory('mysqli', $dbConfig);
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

And then Zend Framework should handle the connection process for you.  Then instead of having a DatabaseService class you just create a model for each table you need like so:

```
<?php

class EndPoints extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'EndPoints';

    /**
     * the default is 'id'. So if your table's primary key field name is 'id' you
     * will not be required to set this.  If your primary key is something like
     * 'EndPointsID' you MUST set this.
     * @var primary key field name
     */
    protected $_primary = 'EndPointsID';
}
```

Doing this will automagically give you access to functions such as fetchRow(), fetchAll(), find(), etc.  Then you can also use Zend_Db_Table_Select for your queries which can be quite useful.  Like so:

```
<?php

$endPointsModel = new EndPoints();
$callIdCount = $endPointsModel->getCallIdCount('2010-04-21 00:00:01', '2010-04-21 00:00:01');
```

Then in your EndPoints model you would create that function like so:

...

```
public function getCallIdCount($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    $cols = array('cnt' => 'count(*)');
    $select = $this->select->setIntegrityCheck(false) // this is crucial
        ->from($this->_name, $cols)
        ->join('CallID', "{$this->_name}.CallID = CallID.CallID", array())
        ->where("{$this->_name}.LastRegister >= ?", $fromDate)
        ->where("{$this->_name}.LastRegister <= ?", $toDate); 

    // if you need to see what the whole query will look like you can do this:
    // echo $select->__toString();
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
{
```